# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 12): A peaceful tree

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, cipher, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123596/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-11-divide-the-cookies-and-milk) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123647/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-13-santa-likes-cards-but-dislikes-dice)</sub>

---

I wish you all ...

[image: peace_tree]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thank you! You too!

You are wishing us

> Lots of tremendously smart and enjoyable puzzles next year

Each bauble represents

> two superimposed semaphore diagrams representing a pair of letters

As requested, the following image shows how to extract the phrase:

> [image]