# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 13): Santa likes cards but dislikes dice

Tags: pattern, word-property, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123637/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-12-a-peaceful-tree) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124658/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-13-stocking-stuffers)</sub>

---

- Santa likes cards but dislikes dice.
- Santa likes time but dislikes space.
- Santa likes horses but dislikes cows.
- Santa likes day but dislikes night.
- Santa likes wraps but dislikes sandwiches.
- Santa likes simple but dislikes trivial.

So what is it that Santa likes or dislikes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Santa likes...

> GIFTS and PRESENTS!

Because...

> Each of the liked words can be preceded by either GIFT or PRESENT to make a two word phrase: 
>  GIFT cards 
>  PRESENT time 
>  GIFT horses 
>  PRESENT day 
>  GIFT wraps 
>  PRESENT simple

Comment: That was quick :-)